# FadeIn with delay jquery

Tags: jquery, delay, fadein

I tryed to add delay to my fadeIn because I want that any div will display in a diffrenet time function but I didnt know how to do that

***My code:***

```
$(function() {
    $('div.grid_4').fadeIn(1000);
});
```

thnx alot.

Comment: $('div.grid_4').delay(1000).fadeIn(1000);

Comment: I did that but it display all the div's after 1 second.

Comment: You have multiple divs that you want to fadeIn with delay?

Comment: You need to explain it. it's not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have 5 div's that there class is .grid_4, i want that any class well display in another time but the class name will be still the same.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Xc6jn/3/ - this is what i want to do, but its not working to me (using wordpress if thats matter)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I completely understood you, but maybe this can help: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v55azcoe/1/)

I used the function

```
each()
```

to count the divs and change the delay automatically.

Comment: I did something like that and its work :). thnx anyway!